# Generate a random amount of numbers and sort them with bubble sort

Tags: c++, arrays, list, sorting

I am new to programming and I am trying to generate an amount of numbers b and then sorting it with bubble sort without using the sort function of list (Because that would be too easy). Since arrays must have a constant value and I cannot put b as the value I'm trying to put the numbers into a list first and then converting the list into a dynamic array to later use bubble sort. How would I convert list1 into an array here?

````
#include "Log.h"
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
void Initlog();
void Log(const char* message);
int main();```



int main()
{
    Initlog();
    int a;
    int b;
    list<int> list1;
    

    cout << "Give how many numbers to generate: "; // Gibt an wie viele Zahlen generiert werden
    cin >> b;


    cout << "Give the biggest possible outcome: "; // Gibt an wie gro? die größte Zahl sein kann
    cin >> a;
    srand(time(0)); // Damit die Zahlen auch halbwegs random sind
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) // Der Loop der solange macht, bis b erreicht ist
    {
        int x = rand()%a; // a steht für die größtmögliche Zahl, x ist was rauskommt
        cout << x << "\n"; // alle entstandenen Zahlen werden angezeigt
        list1.push_back(x); // Zahlen werden in eine Liste links nach rechts gesteckt
    }

    cout << "The list after inserting all elements is : ";
    for (list<int>::iterator i = list1.begin(); i != list1.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << " "; // Inhalt der Liste wird ausgelesen
    cout << endl;


    std::cin.get();
}
````

Comment: What about using a `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: You can allocate sufficient memory for your array using `new int[b]`, which gives you a pointer to the array of size `b`. Please do not forget to call `delete[]` on the pointer later though. Or you can use `std::vector<int>`, `resize` it to `b` and use it like an array (and not worry about memory management.

Comment: Please forget about `new int[b]`. It's almost always better to use `std::vector` and best to use `vector.at(i)` instead of `vector[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer to use `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> data;  
for (int index = 0; index < b; ++index)
{
    int x = rand() % a;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    data.push_back(x);
}
// The std::vector can be treated as an array.
```

To answer your question about converting `std::list` to an array:

```
std::list<int>::iterator iter = list1.begin();
std::list<int>::iterator end_iter = list1.end();
int * pointer_to_array = new int [list1.size()];

for (int *p = pointer_to_array;
     iter != end_iter;
     ++iter)
{
    *p++ = *iter;
}
```

The code above is one of many techniques to convert a `std::list` to an array.  The array must use dynamic memory because the quantity of data is not known at compile time.

*Note: prefer `std::vector` because it handles memory allocation and deallocation for you.*

Comment: don't forget to `delete` what you've `new`ed

Comment: *The std::vector can be treated as an array.* and in the cases where it can't, like calling a function that need a pointer to an array, you can get the `vector`'s backing array with a call to `data`.

Comment: The first code should include `data.reserve(b)`. The second code could use `std::copy(list1.cbegin(), list.cend() - 1, pointer_to_array)`. You could have also used vector in the second code.